# PouchDB does not replicate all docs from the remote database

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I'm currently developing an Ionic app and I'm using cloudant as a remote database and pouchdb as a local database on the phone. For some reason my initial replication sometimes doesn't fully replicate all the docs on the remote database, I've tried several things like setting: live: true, retry: true, but if the replication doesn't complete the first time, then it never updates the docs that weren't replicated.

`database = new PouchDB('test'),
    remote = new PouchDB('URL'),
    opts = {
      retry: true,
      live: true
    };`

```
database.replicate.from(remote,[opts]).then(function (result) {

  console.log(database._docCount);

}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Strange. Firstly, during debugging and troubleshooting now, consider disabling the `live:true`  and `retyry:true` options. That way, you should be able to see any errors more quickly--that is, the library will not quietly squelch those errors. Once you have solved this problem, re-enable it. If you see any errors or other information, can you please add it to this question?

Comment: Next, sometimes document conflicts and deleted revisions can cause unexpected things. Can you please fetch the doc, both on your local PouchDB and your remote Cloudant account, **showing revision info**. On PouchDB, you need `options.revs_info = true` and on Cloudant, you need to add `?revs_info=true`. Can you please update the question with your results? Whatever your results will be, it will be helpful.